# Get Box Plot From Redundant Rows

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [12124,12124,5687,5687,7892], 
                   'A': [np.nan,np.nan,3.05,3.05,np.nan],'B':[1.05,1.05,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'D':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7.09]})
```

[image: Table Data]

I want to get box plot of columns A, B, C, and D, where the redundant row values in each column needs to be counted once only. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit unclear. Please see how to ask a good pandas question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples For a boxplot, you will need to include more copy and pasteable rows of data (no images) in your question. You can't create a good boxplot from just a rows of data

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates().boxplot(column=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])` ??

Comment: In this case, id and the individual columns needs to be combined as one composite key. Because the same value 3.05 in Column A can appear on column A again.

Comment: `drop_duplicates` without a subset will only drop rows if the entire row matches.

Comment: So that's the solution then @HenryEcker

Answer (score 1):

Because panda can only deal with the dataFrame that every column has same length as well as every row has same length. In other words, only frame-shape data could be process. If null values need to be counted only once, it may conflict the principles of "panda" package. Here is my suggestion: you could **transform the dataframe into list** .
[The detailed code of transforming the dataFrame into list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGoXI.jpg)
Then you could try to plot the box plot from the list data and index column.